# Bootstrap navbar isn't working correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Every time I click on one of my links that I have in my navbar, it "disappears". I put that in quotes because I have my website background set as white, and the default hover and selection color is white. How do I change the default hover and selection color with the default bootstrap template? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the current code that you are using?

Comment: Make use of CSS. That is what they are meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you haven't made any changes to the nav classes something as simple as

```
.navbar .nav li a:hover {
color: #000;
}
```

Comment: This worked for the hovering, but when I click on the link, it is still white. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do the same for when the link is active using a:active selector. Please mark my solution as accepted if it helped you with your question

Comment: This is what I did, but it still "disappears" after being clicked:

Comment: .navbar .nav li a:active {
 color: #33ccff;
}

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in your question please

Comment: .navbar .nav li a:active {
 color: #33ccff;
    }

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jfU1sS-Jow&feature=youtu.be